# Opacity with a pgf-umlcd diagram

Tags: pgf-umlcd

Can anyone help me get an opacity `scope` to work correctly with `pgf-umlcd` inheritance relation?

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{pgf-umlcd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
   \begin{scope}[opacity=0.3]
      \begin{class}{Foo}{0, 2cm}
      \end{class}
      \begin{class}{Bar}{0, 0cm}
         \inherit{Foo}
      \end{class}
   \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Notice the inheritance relation doesn't get the reduced opacity.

[image: Result2]

Comment: I don't quite understand your use of `transparency group` here. Isn't just opacity what you need? `\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{pgf-umlcd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
   \begin{scope}[opacity=0.5]
      \begin{class}{Foo}{0, 2cm}
      \end{class}
      \begin{class}{Bar}{0, 0cm}
         \inherit{Foo}
      \end{class}
   \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}`

Comment: Indeed. Edited question and made the resulting image more clear.

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear to me why this happens, but there are a couple of workarounds. One is to append the opacity setting to the `umlcd style inherit line` style in addition, another is to use `every path/.append style={opacity=0.3}`.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf-umlcd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
   \begin{scope}[
      %opacity=0.3,umlcd style inherit line/.append style={opacity=0.3},
      every path/.append style={opacity=0.3}
     ]
      \begin{class}{Foo}{0, 2cm}
      \end{class}
      \begin{class}{Bar}{0, 0cm}
         \inherit{Foo}
      \end{class}
   \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```